# How can I ensure that the appropriate language version of a string resource is loaded at runtime?

Tags: .net, resources, internationalization, locale, resourcemanager

I have a string resource file called "strings.resx" in my VB.NET project, defined as an embedded resource.  I have another file called `strings.es.resx`, which contains all of the same strings in Spanish.  I'm loading the resource at runtime using the following code:

```
MyStrings = New ResourceManager("myprog.strings", GetType(MainForm).Assembly)
```

I've set the language locale to Espanol in Windows and logged back in, but I'm still getting the English string resources loading when the above is executed.  How can I load the spanish resources if the Windows locale is ES?  I was expecting it to be handled automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the `System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture` property - it has a habit of being fixed to en-US.

If it is, try setting it to the same as `CurrentCulture`.

**Update**

Since that didn't work, check that the the output folder of your application has an `es` folder, inside which is a dll called strings.resources.dll.  If not, then, basically, the resource manager is not finding the culture-specific string resource, because it's not there, in which case copy them in and it should work.

Comment: CurrentUICulture is es-ES.  The form resources are localised ok, it's just these "literal" values I use in code that seem to always be the neutral culture.

Comment: @Robinson - If you're using the `GetString(string)` method of `ResourceManager`, have you/could you try the explicit `GetString(string, CultureInfo)` overload, and pass the Spanish culture unambiguously please?
If it still doesn't work, then my guess is it's not finding your resources file in the bin folder

Comment: Duh!  My mistake...  The strings are loading correctly.  I'm just doing something else thereafter (reading from an english settings file) that contains the English version of the strings.  Will mark your answer correct for your efforts as the reason was my own stupidity :p.

Comment: @Robinson - if you were here with me in my office, then I would have just fulfilled the role of 'the cardboard programmer'. It's a very important job :)

Answer (score 0):

*DISCLAIMER* - this is all from memory and may not be 100% accurate :-)

.NET resources are loaded using `Thread.CurrentUICulture` (unless you explicitly override it when loading resources in code). `Thread.CurrentUICulture` is set by the UI language used in your installation of Windows, and cannot be changed. This is not the same as `Thread.CurrentCulture`, which is set in Control Panel, and can be changed at any time.

For example, on my PC, `CurrentCulture` returns `"en-GB"` because that's where I am, but `CurrentUICulture` returns `"en-US"` because Microsoft only provide one English language version of Windows.

Comment: You **CAN** set Thread.CurrentUICulture - ResourceManager actually responds to this and loads resource sets for this culture.